# Prove that if $ST=I$. Then $\text{dim}(U)\le\text{dim}(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm hoping someone could help me with the following problem. Let $S\in\mathcal{L}(V,U)$ and $T\in\mathcal{L}(U,V)$. Prove that if $ST=I$. Then $\text{dim}(U)\le\text{dim}(V)$

Comment: We have $ST\in \mathcal L(U,W)$. What would $I$ mean in such a case? Also, may we assume the vector spaces are finite dimensional?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that we have $W=U,$ otherwise $ST=I$ makes no sense. If we assume that $U$ and $V$ are finite-dimensional, we get

$$ \dim V = \dim ker(S)+ \dim im(S).$$

From $U= im (ST) \subseteq im(S) \subseteq U,$ we see that $im(S) =U.$

Hence we derive

$$ \dim V = \dim ker(S)+ \dim U \ge \dim U.$$

Comment: Thank you for taking the time!